# echo foreach from 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have 2 arrays containing the following values from mysql query

```
$Array1 =
(
[0] => john
[1] => nick
[2] => mike
[3] => eva
[4] => mary
) 

$Array2 =
(
[0] => Array ( [name] => john [color] =>black )
[1] => Array ( [name] => john [color] =>red )
[2] => Array ( [name] => mike [color] =>yellow )
[3] => Array ( [name] => eva [color] =>purple )
[4] => Array ( [name] => eva [color] =>green )
[5] => Array ( [name] => mary [color] =>orange )
[6] => Array ( [name] => mary [color] =>white )
[7] => Array ( [name] => george [color] =>purple )
[8] => Array ( [name] => phil [color] =>green )
[9] => Array ( [name] => toni [color] =>orange )
[10] => Array ( [name] => amanda [color] =>white )

)
```

I want to `echo` for each person in `$array1` all colors in `$array2`.

Comment: And what have you tried? This should be a pretty simple solution if you use a `foreach` inside a `foreach`, but you need to show some effort first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
foreach($Array1 as $value)
    foreach($Array2 as $v)
       echo $v['name'] === $value ? $v['color'] : '';
```

#### [Example](https://eval.in/242423)

Comment: In this answer you don't display the first names (you did on the example).

Comment: @A.L : Please, stop editing, I don't want to distract people from the concept by posting the code from _eval.in_ (the code I've added there is for output purposes, to make it demonstrative.).

Comment: Ok, sorry for the multiple edits. Anyway I think that without the first names, the output of this code is just a list of unrelated colors. Remember *While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.*.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below

```
<?php
$Array1 = array
(
0 => "john",
1 => "nick",
2 => "mike",
3 => "eva",
4 => "mary",
);

$Array2 =array
(
0 => Array ( "name" => "john" ,"color" =>"black" ),
1 => Array ( "name" => "john" ,"color" =>"red" ),
2 => Array ( "name" => "mike" ,"color" =>"yellow" ),
3 => Array ( "name" => "eva" ,"color" =>"purple" ),
4 => Array ( "name" => "eva" ,"color" =>"green" ),
5 => Array ( "name" => "mary" ,"color" =>"orange" ),
6 => Array ( "name" => "mary" ,"color" =>"white" ),
7 => Array ( "name" => "george" ,"color" =>"purple" ),
8 => Array ( "name" => "phil" ,"color" =>"green" ),
9 => Array ( "name"=> "toni" ,"color" =>"orange" ),
10 => Array ( "name" => "amanda" ,"color" =>"white"),

);
            foreach($Array1 as $t){
                foreach($Array2 as $p){
                   if($p['name'] == $t) {
            echo $p['color'];
            }
            }
}
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
$Array1 = array("john", "nick", "mike", "eva", "mary");

$Array2 = array(
        array ("name" => "john", "color" => "black" ),
        array ( "name" => "john", "color" => "red" ),
        array ( "name" => "mike", "color" => "yellow" ),
        array ( "name" => "eva", "color" => "purple" ),
        array ( "name" => "eva", "color" => "green" ),
        array ( "name" => "mary", "color" => "orange" ),
        array ( "name" => "mary", "color" => "white" ),
        array ( "name" => "george", "color" => "purple" ),
        array ( "name" => "phil", "color" => "green" ),
        array ( "name"=> "toni", "color" => "orange" ),
        array ( "name" => "amanda", "color" => "white")
);

foreach($Array1 as $val1)
    foreach($Array2 as $val2)
       echo $val2['name'] === $val1 ? $val2['color'] . "<br>" : '';
```

Comment: Hello, I don't want to be rude or something, but do you find it effective or useful to post the exact same answer that I did?

Comment: Apologies. Started posting before I saw yours. Was just trying to help. Haven't been a contributor here, so I'm new to it.